# Creating Android Activity to show Facebook status posts of a specific FB page

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, api

I am new to this and this is my first post here on StackOverflow.  Be gentle haha.

I am trying to create a activity inside of my android app to display the recent posts of a Facebook page I run.

I would like it to display from within the app and not in a new browser window of any kind.

I am using Eclipse, have the Facebook SDK installed and my app referencing it as a library, I just don't know where to go from here.

Any suggestions as to the easiest ways to do that?

It should be mentioned that I would need you to start at step ONE haha.